# Solve linear equation system with Gauss

Tags: matrices

I have the following matrix and have to see if it has solutions depending on $a$. My solution:

$M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & a^2 &| &1 \\
   -1 & -1& | & -a \\
   1 & a & | & a
  \end{array} } \right]
$

My attemp was:
Changing first with third line

$=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & a & | & a \\
   -1 & -1& | & -a \\
   a & a^2 &| &1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

Add the first row to the second one

$=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & a & | & a \\
   0 & a-1& | & 0 \\
   a & a^2 &| &1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

Add the $-a$ of the first line to the third line

$=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & a & | & a \\
   0 & a-1& | & 0 \\
   0 & 0 &| &1-a^2 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

From $0=1-a^2$there we can obtain that the LES has a solution if $a=+/-1$

Is this a valid solution to the problem and is there a free variable?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
M=
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
a  & a^2 & 1 \\
-1 & -1  & -a \\
1  & a   & a
\end{array}\right]
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
1  & a   & a \\
-1 & -1  & -a \\
a  & a^2 & 1
\end{array}\right]
&&R_1\leftrightarrow R_3
\\[4px]&\to
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
1  & a   & a \\
0  & a-1  & 0 \\
0  & 0 & 1-a^2
\end{array}\right]
&&\begin{aligned}R_2&\gets R_2+R_1\\R_3&\gets R_3-aR_1\end{aligned}
\end{align}
Your work was pretty good.

Now you have to distinguish the cases $a=1$, $a=-1$, $a\ne\pm1$

#### Case $a=1$

The matrix becomes
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
and the system has infinitely many solutions
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1-h \\ h \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + h\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

#### Case $a=-1$

The matrix becomes
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & -1   & -1 \\
0 & 2  & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
\to
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
and the system has a single solution $\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

#### Case $a\ne\pm1$

No solution.

Answer (score 0):

If $a=\pm 1$, then indeed we have a solution.

Now $a=1$, the second row become the zero row, and hence there is a free variable. Can you write down the general solution?

If $a=-1$, the second row is not a zero row, there is no free variable. It has a unique solution.

Comment: but for $a=-1$ $x_2$ has to be $0$ so the row becomes a zero row again, doesn't it?

Comment: $x_2=0$ is true, but the second row is $[0, -2, 0]$ which is not a zero row.

Comment: okay, thank you! And the transformations are correct?

Comment: And for $a=1$ the general solution should be $L=[1-t, t]$, shouldn't it? Because $x_1=1-x_2$ and $x_2=t$ (or any other name)? And for $a-1$ the solution is $[a,0]$, right?

Comment: Your Gaussian elimination step looks fine. if $a=1$, the general solution is indeed $(1-t,t)$ where $t$ is a free parameter. If $a=-1$, we have $x_2=0$, and the solution is $(a,0)=(-1,0)$.